# @Pattern validation on a blank field

Tags: java, regex, bean-validation

I am using validation annotations to validate the Email field, Here the email field is not mandatory, Still when I click on submit, It is validating and throwing error message when the field is empty,

Here are the annotations:

```
@Pattern(regexp = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$", 
            message = "registration.label.useremailformat.invalidformat")
@Size(min = 6, max = 20, message = "registration.label.useremail.length")
@SafeHtml
private String userEmailId;
```

How can I skip @Pattern validation when the email field is empty and validate only when the value is given? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: wrong position of `-` in character class

Comment: The pattern requires some text to be present. Try `regexp = "^(?:[_A-Za-z0-9-+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,}))?$"`. Also, check the `min` param.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew - not displaying any error msg, but form is not getting submitted

Comment: Yes, maybe because of the `@Size` restriction. What if you remove the Size check and just use `regexp = "^(?:(?=.{6,20}$)[_A-Za-z0-9-+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z‌​]{2,}))?$"`? See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/eP7eA4/1).

Comment: I removed @Size as well, still not working

Comment: @Thej: What is working? `regexp = "^(?:(?=.{6,20}$)[_A-Za-z0-9-+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+‌​)*(\\.[A-Za-z‌​]{2,}))?$"`? Shall I post that and explain?

Comment: I posted the answer since it seems working for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem is that the `@Size` restriction does not allow form submission even after making the whole regex pattern optional.

The workaround I suggest is moving the size restriction into the regex pattern:

```
regexp = "^(?:(?=.{6,20}$)[_A-Za-z0-9-+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+‌​‌​)*(\\.[A-Za-z‌​]{2,}))?$"
```

Where the outer `(?:...)?` encloses your pattern making it possible to match an empty string, and `(?=.{6,20}$)` is a positive lookahead that - before matching the pattern - checks if there are 6 to 20 characters in the text. If there are fewer or more, the match is failed.

The only disadvantage is that you can only display one error message with it.

Answer (score 9):

Modify your regexp to allow empty string *and* remove `@Size`:

```
@Pattern("^$|(<<old regexp>>)")
@SafeHtml
private String userEmailId;
```

... where `<<old regex>>` is a placeholder for your current lengthy regexp.